# Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined at /node_modules/bindings/bindings.js with electron and install serialport

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, vue-cli, node-serialport

```
1.  npm install -g node-gyp
2.  npm install serialport -S
3.  npm install electron-rebuild -D
4. ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild.cmd
```

and then, rebuild  [complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMXTx.png).

And when I run this command: `npm run electron:serve`
I have an error into inspect of browser electron like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyDxM.png).

And if I enter into `bindings.js` code I can find where is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRqAt.png):

```
nodePreGyp:
  'node-v' +
    process.versions.modules
```

there is my package.json file:

```js
{"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bindings": "^1.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "echarts": "^5.0.0",
    "element-resize-detector": "^1.2.1",
    "element-ui": "^2.14.1",
    "serialport": "^9.0.7",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.5.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.22.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "webstomp-client": "^1.2.6",
    "ws": "^7.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^7.1.9",
    "electron-rebuild": "^2.3.5",
    "electron-builder": "^20.19.2",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "__npminstall_done": false
}
```

Can you tell me where is the problem or help me to more understand how fix this?

Comment: node-gyp depends on your OS and it seems that your issue dealing with this... what is your OS ? Are you validate your good install of node-gyp ?

Comment: I use 'node-gyp list' command,the gyo info show ' gyp info it worked if it ends with ok,gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2,gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64'  :)  
my os  is win 10 ,x64

Comment: thank you so much ,I am looking forword your replay.

Comment: @user15280394 did you ever figure this out?  I have the same issue and I think its to do with serialport

Answer (score 0):

If you work with electron with VueJS please see https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue
already build this all code and also helpful

First Time Face Same issue implementing existing VueJS Project SerialPort Package with Electron

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9t9n.png)

```js
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h2>Hello world</h2>

    <button @click="listMyPorts">Show Ports</button>

    <pre v-if="msg.length">{{msg}}</pre>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  const serialport = require('serialport')

  export default {
    name: 'landing-page',
    data: () => ({
      msg: []
    }),
    methods: {
      async  listSerialPorts () {
        await serialport.list().then((ports, err) => {
          if (err) {
            this.msg.push(err.message)
            return
          } else {
            this.msg.push('')
          }
          console.log('ports', ports)
          this.msg.push(ports)

          if (ports.length === 0) {
            this.msg.push('No ports discovered')
          }
        })
      },
      listMyPorts () {
        let vm = this
        setTimeout(function listPorts () {
          vm.listSerialPorts()
          setTimeout(listPorts, 2000)
        }, 2000)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```